# Aligning formulae in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

```
\forall x\    &0 \neq S(x)\\
\forall x,y\  &S(x) = S(y) \implies x = y\\
\forall x\    &x + 0 = x\\
\forall x,y\  &x + S(y) = S(x + y)\\
\forall x\    &x \cdot 0 = 0\\
\forall x,y\  &x \cdot S(y) = x \cdot y + x
```

I want to align the above formulae such as displayed in the plain text.

How can I do that in LaTeX?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. It looks like you are trying to align by using ampersands (&) but because you've not provided any more code, I can't see what you have tried. Are you using align or a table for example?

Comment: @JJAD I tried using the align environment but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& \forall  x\ &&0 \neq S(x)\\
&\forall x,y\ &&S(x) = S(y) \implies x = y\\
&\forall   x\ &&x + 0 = x\\
&\forall x,y\ &&x + S(y) = S(x + y)\\
&\forall   x\ &&x \cdot 0 = 0\\
&\forall x,y\ &&x \cdot S(y) = x \cdot y + x
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mentioning `\ ` on a single (relevant) line should  yield the result as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{math}
\begin{array}{ll}
\forall x\    &0 \neq S(x)\\
\forall x,y\  &S(x) = S(y) \implies x = y\\
\forall x\    &x + 0 = x\\
\forall x,y\  &x + S(y) = S(x + y)\\
\forall x\    &x \cdot 0 = 0\\
\forall x,y\  &x \cdot S(y) = x \cdot y + x
\end{array}
\end{math}
```

Comment: ...interesting... `\begin{math}`...`\end{math}`...